# How to make object able to return its properties when triggered by print function

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

In python if we print some object, it will show their properties when triggered by print function.
For example:

```
print(int(69)) # 69
```

Unlike my own defined class like this:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self,oke):
    self.oke = oke

print(Foo('yeah')) # <__main__.Foo object at 0x000001EB00CDEEB0>
```

Why It doesn't return oke properties? Instead it show memory address of object?

I expect the output will be:

```
Foo(oke='yeah')
```

I know I can define method getter `get_oke()`, but I want see all properties in an object at once print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `__repr__` method to your class.

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

> If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,oke):
        self.oke = oke

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Foo(oke="{self.oke}")'


print(Foo('yeah'))  # Foo(oke="yeah")
```